# how to load a select widget with queryset data in django forms

Tags: django, forms, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to load a dynamic select widget in my form with queryset data using the following code:

forms.py

```
class TransactionForm(forms.Form):
    # Payment methods
    payment_meth = []
    # form fields
    trans_amount = forms.IntegerField(label="Amount", min_value=0)
    payment_method = forms.CharField(
        label='Payment method',
        widget=forms.Select(
            choices=payment_meth
            )
    )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    username = self.request.user.username
    self.get_mm_details = MMDetails.objects.filter(username=username)
    self.get_card_details = CardDetails.objects.filter(username=username)
    # add payment methods details to a dictionary
    for method in self.get_mm_details:
        entry = ()
        entry += (method.method_name,)
        entry += (method.method_name,)
        self.payment_meth.append(entry)
    for method in self.get_card_details:
        entry = ()
        entry += (method.method_name,)
        entry += (method.method_name,)
        self.payment_meth.append(entry)
    super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

View.py

```
form = TransactionForm(request=request)
```

What can I do to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Use `forms.ChoiceField` instead of `forms.CharField` and then set the choices in the `init` method like this:

```
class TransactionForm(forms.Form):
    # Payment methods
    payment_meth = []
    # form fields
    trans_amount = forms.IntegerField(label="Amount", min_value=0)
    payment_method = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Payment method',
        choices=payment_meth
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        username = self.request.user.username
        self.get_mm_details = MMDetails.objects.filter(username=username)
        self.get_card_details = CardDetails.objects.filter(username=username)
        # add payment methods details to a dictionary
        for method in self.get_mm_details:
            entry = ()
            entry += (method.method_name,)
            entry += (method.method_name,)
            self.payment_meth.append(entry)
        for method in self.get_card_details:
            entry = ()
            entry += (method.method_name,)
            entry += (method.method_name,)
            self.payment_meth.append(entry)
        super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['payment_method'].choices = self.payment_meth
```

Comment: The dropdown is still empty,

Comment: I made a mistake on filter(username=username), its supposed to be filter(username=self.request.user)